# Is is possible to send a variable using python's pynput?

Tags: python, pynput

I have made a python script to do some math for me.
I then used this pynput script

```
import pynput
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time

keyboard = Controller()

def type(char):
    keyboard.press(char)
    keyboard.release(char)

output = "144"
type(output)
```

The aim is to send the variable "Output" from my keys and that var - output - is always an integer with a length between 1 digit and 3 digits. When I run it it replies with

```
  File "C:/Users/matth/OneDrive/Documents/My programs/TTRockstars/BIG BREAK/type.py", line 14, in <module>
    type(output)
  File "C:/Users/matth/OneDrive/Documents/My programs/TTRockstars/BIG BREAK/type.py", line 8, in type
    keyboard.press(char)
  File "C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pynput\keyboard\_base.py", line 362, in press
    resolved = self._resolve(key)
  File "C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pynput\keyboard\_base.py", line 556, in _resolve
    raise ValueError(key)
ValueError: 144
```

I don't know if pynput is the right way to go?? or is there an alternative?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to use `pynput` to type in the string `output`?

Comment: Can I ask you why you don't use input() instead of that?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA Yes

Comment: @Tané It is just a snippet of a big program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A suggestion:python has a function called `type()`.In your code,you have redefined it.And your code can be:

```
import pynput
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time

keyboard = Controller()

def Type(char):
    pressList = list(char)
    for i in pressList:
        keyboard.press(i)
        keyboard.release(i)

output = "144"
Type(output)
```

When you run this code.It will press "1","4","4".